# bookmark+ highlighting problem

Tags: faces, highlighting, bookmarks, customize-face, bookmark+

I am trying to use bookmark+, but I am unable to get the highlighting as I wish (or, maybe, as I wrongly expect?):
When I change the default highlight of a bookmark, I only see the purple flag, but never the colored file name (e.g. tt)
I do see colors like in the second line for dired bookmarks.

[image: Snapshot of 2 bookmarks]

What I would like to achieve:
Change the color/highlighting of a bookmark name according to my own scheme, in a quite easy way.
I noticed that I get a lot of questions about style and face when I try to change the highlighting - but it never made any difference for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the cursor on the bookmark name and use `C-u C-x =`. Near the bottom of buffer `*Help*` you'll see the name(s) of the face(s) on the text at the cursor. Then `M-x customize-face` for that face.

I'm guessing the face you need to customize is `bmkp-local-file-without-region`. By default it doesn't look different from the default font (e.g., just black text).

`M-x list-faces-display` shows *all* current faces. Those used by [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) have names with prefix `bmkp`:

- `bmkp-*-mark`
- `bmkp->-mark`
- `bmkp-D-mark`
- `bmkp-X-mark`
- `bmkp-a-mark`
- `bmkp-bad-bookmark`
- `bmkp-bookmark-file`
- `bmkp-bookmark-list`
- `bmkp-buffer`
- `bmkp-desktop`
- `bmkp-file-handler`
- `bmkp-function`
- `bmkp-gnus`
- `bmkp-heading`
- `bmkp-info`
- `bmkp-light-autonamed`
- `bmkp-light-autonamed-region`
- `bmkp-light-fringe-autonamed`
- `bmkp-light-fringe-non-autonamed`
- `bmkp-light-mark`
- `bmkp-light-non-autonamed`
- `bmkp-light-non-autonamed-region`
- `bmkp-local-directory`
- `bmkp-local-file-with-region`
- `bmkp-local-file-without-region`
- `bmkp-man`
- `bmkp-no-jump`
- `bmkp-no-local`
- `bmkp-non-file`
- `bmkp-remote-file`
- `bmkp-sequence`
- `bmkp-snippet`
- `bmkp-su-or-sudo`
- `bmkp-t-mark`
- `bmkp-url`
- `bmkp-variable-list`

In buffer `*Bookmark List*`, if you use `?` or `C-h m` you'll see their descriptions listed, showing their highlights. E.g., face `bmkp-local-file-without-region` shows this description with that face (same as face `default`, by default): **Local file with no region**.

---

**UPDATE** after your comment that says that you tried `HH` and `H+`, and that you want to change how a bookmark is lighted in buffer `*Bookmark List*`.

Bookmarks are highlighted in various ways (customizable) *at their bookmarked locations (destinations)*.

Bookmark names/lines in `*Bookmark List*` are highlighted according to their types. If a bookmark has its own (destination) highlighting defined then, in  `*Bookmark List*` a "purple flag" (face `bmkp-light-mark`), as you mentioned and show, is shown next to each one whose location will be highlighted (when you visit it).

In `*Bookmark List*`, `HH` turns on (destination) highlighting for the bookmark listed on the current line. `H+` defines how the bookmark on the current line will be highlighted (at its destination).

There's no feature to highlight arbitrary bookmarks in `*Bookmark List*`. That would interfere with highlighting to show the bookmark types. (You could  copy the definition of function `bmkp-bmenu-list-1` and modify it to do that, I guess.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. If I edit and change `bmkp-local-file-without-region`, every bookmark of this kind (i.e. 99 percent in my case) ends up with this color, which makes no difference then. I was hoping that `HH` or `H+` could be used to give different colors to bookmarks, but for some reason I do not see any change when I use these shortcuts. Maybe I just misunderstand what `HH` etc. are doing. But assigning colors to bookmarks would be really cool.